# A client for existing wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, soapui

I have a wsdl, all tests are applied in soapUI.The Test was succesfull.
Meanwhile, I don't know how will I integrate our program.
When all project has been done in SoapUI, I used WSDL2JAVA axis2.
It put a lot of class for me in the folder.
How will I combine?
I need a only simple client.
any simple method to do it?
I have also timestamp,username,keystore and a truststore.
Can AXIS2 put in classes for me ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to build and package your web service client. The following Maven POM is a skeleton that has goals to generate your client classes from a WSDL and package the whole project as a JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>webservice-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-a-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>myService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```